# User can't stop Oracle listener (TNS-01190)

Tags: linux, oracle, listener

I have Oracle 10g installed on RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.

I have 2 users that use Oracle:

```
uid=501(user1) gid=502(group1) groupes=500(oinstall),501(dba),502(group1)
```

and

```
uid=500(oracle) gid=500(oinstall) groupes=500(oinstall),501(dba),502(group1)
```

When a user tries to stop a listener that was started *by the other user*, I get this error:

```
TNS-01190: The user is not authorized to execute the requested listener command
```

How can I allow both users to stop the listener, regardless of who started it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description for the message you're seeing is:

> Cause: Most of the listener administrative commands are only intended
>   to be issued by privileged users, for example DBAs or system
>   administrators. If the listener password is not set, then the listener
>   only accepts administrative requests from LSNRCTL running with the
>   same OS credentials, or running as a local administrator (also
>   referred to as super user).
>
> Action: If an authorized user is attempting the command, then make
>   sure that LSNRCTL is executed with the same OS user credentials as the
>   running listener, or as a local administrator.

Unless you want to get into `setuid` wrappers, you need to have a password set for your listener. There's a good summary of how to set that up [here](http://www.petefinnigan.com/ramblings/set_listener_password.htm), if you haven't already done so.

Then if you start the listener as normal as `oracle`, you can shut it down as `user1` by going into the interactive mode of the controller, enter command 'set password', and enter the password for the listener:

```
$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 12-NOV-2012 14:55:29

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> stop
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
TNS-01190: The user is not authorized to execute the requested listener command
LSNRCTL> set password
Password: <secret>
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> stop
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL>
```

... and it should shut down. I know this is a different O/S and version but the principle is the same. And the reverse is true; if you start it as `user1`, you need to `set password` to be able to shut it down as `oracle`.

---

However, [this is deprecated from 11gR2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/listenercfg.htm#i486171). The [manual mentons](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/mignet.htm#NETRF1971) using `ssh` or OEM, but you could also just make `user1` switch to the `oracle` account to start and stop the listener via `su`. Obviously that gives them full DBA access, it isn't restricted to the listener, which is the case for `ssh` too.

I'm not sure why you'd want anyone you didn't trust to administer the database to be able to mess with the listener, or why you need to shut it down and start it up often enough for this to be an issue.

Comment: I'll add that having multiple users being able to do this is bad, and might not be supported. Just thinking that it's the listener process that does a `fork()` (maybe exec, my memory is bad) to establish a dedicated connection and the resulting process connects to a big shared memory segment. Security problems abound if the permissions are set accordingly. Just a thought.

Comment: @Phil - it is supported (or was, it's deprecated from 11gR2), but I originally had a comment querying why you'd want to do this, which I removed because I'd worded it unintentionally harshly. Agree that the security implications need to be given serious thought, but that's true for everything of course...

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole , I think i'm just gonna use setuid. when i do chmod 6755 lsnrctl then user1 can stop listener if started by oracle (but not the inverse)

Comment: I wanted every body to be able to start and stop listener because i wrote some scripts witch changes the listener.ora and i want to restart the listener so changes will take effect for the rest of script.

Comment: Changing permissions on an Oracle-installed binary, or messing with the installation at all unless under direction from Oracle Support, isn't generally a good idea. Apart from anything else, the binary might be relinked by a patch. I was thinking more of a `setuid` wrapper, possibly just restricted `sudo`. Just out of interest, what are you changing in the `listener.ora`?

Comment: I was writing a script that configures a physical standby database. So I change `listener.ora` to add the standby database in it. The script is useful for me because i do a lot of tests and when there is many problem i just re-install the whole system (on VMware).

Answer (score -2):

Login as `sysdba`
and run:

```
alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;

alter system register;
```

It worked form me.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This just causes the instance to register with the listener but doesn't solve the problem how to restart the listener.

Answer (score -2):

```
alter system 
    set LOCAL_LISTENER='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;

alter system register;
```

worked for me too